Text Format in LARAVEL PHP Export Excel
result export excel
I want to change the data format of the excel export result from general to text.
but I tried various ways and didn't get the right result, does anyone know how to fix this code?
public function columnFormats(): array
    {

        return [
            //FORMAT general ke text
            'A' => DataType::TYPE_STRING,
        ];
    }


"I didn't get the right result" is very vague. What is the result you get, what is the result you want?

I'm sorry, I mean when I download the excel result the data in excel has a “general” data type format, I want to convert the data in excel to a “text” data type format.

Well column A is in the TYPE_STRING with the code posted? Column F (screenshot) is not. I guess you are using Maatwebsite\Excel?

I used numberformat::FORMAT_TEXT too before but my user checked it in excel using the istext() formula and the result was false, I'm confused about what else to use :)

Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Maybe this will solve your problem (in the docs) Docs value binder

In Maatwebsite\Excel you can change the datatype of the columns when implementing
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
class YourExport implements WithColumnFormatting /* and the other needed implements */

Next you add code like in your question: I've done this in the past using
public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [

        'E' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
        'H' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,

    ];
}

